# Добавить пункт в контекстное меню Android [решено]

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли в Android возможность добавлять пункты в контекстное меню, например, звонка в журнале или напоминалки в календаре?
[image: Вот сюда, например]

Comment: Нет, нужно достать исходники приложения, в них добавить этот пункт с функционалом и обратно запаковать, затем установить на телефон. Хотя может есть секретные пути, но думаю что их нет.

Comment: написать свой журнал или календарь с блекджеком и ну этими, вы поняли:)

Comment: ясно, спасибо большое, товарищи!!!
А насчет блекджека и "ну этого", я подумаю ;)